# Problematic integral

Tags: integration, functions

Yesterday I started to solve the integral of $\frac{1}{x^5+1}$ in $dx$ so I started in this way:
$$ \int \frac{1}{x^5+1} dx = \int \frac{1+x^5-x^5}{x^5+1}dx = \int \frac{x^5+1}{x^5+1}dx - \int \frac{x^5}{x^5+1}dx = x-\int \frac{x^5}{x^5+1}dx $$

Then I tried to solve the last integral using method by parts but I meet only hypergeometric functions which I don't know for the moment. Using wolfram alpha I saw the solution of $\int\frac{1}{x^5+1}dx$ and it has no strange functions that I don't know so can I solve it having the possibility to use substitutions, method by parts and algebric manipulation? I need your help and suggestions, thank you in advance!!(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Your integral is not problematic if you decompose the integrand in partial fractions, each denominator being of the form $x-a_i$ where $a_i$ represents the $i^{th}$ root of $x^5+1=0$. You will arrive to some  logarithms of complex numbers which , in turn, simplify to logarithms of real numbers and $\tan ^{-1}$'s.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to semplify logarithms of complex numbers in logarithms of real numbers... Are there some website where it is explained clearly?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm